# Interactive grid in Oracle APEX - Only 40 rows are selected, if I do 'Select All'

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an updatable interactive grid with 200 rows. If I do a select all on the grid, only 40 records gets selected. But then I scroll further down and then again do a select all, another 40 records i.e total of 80 records gets selected.
If I scroll down till the end and do a select all, then all the 200 records gets selected.So, it appears that the rows gets selected in the chunks of 40 each time.

Is it a bug/feature of interactive grid that the complete grid can't be selected at once, unless we scroll down till the end. This happens specifically if my report Pagination is set to 'Scroll'.  For pagination type 'Page', everything works as expected.

Please suggest, how can I select all rows for report pagination type 'Scroll'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably Scroll type pagination does work in this way. I have checked the sample application for interactive grid and there also it is the same behaviour. Hence closing this issue.