# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid select all only select 1 page records

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a button “Select All” and it has a true dynamic cation “JS Function” to select all the records on the interactive Grid.

```
apex.region(“payment_info”).widget()
     .interactiveGrid(“getViews”, “grid”).view$.grid(“selectAll”);
```

This function only selects the record on the page I am currently focusing on.  I want to select all the records from all the pages in that Interactive Grid.

NOTE: I need to keep the pagination of the IG. I cannot have the page as a scroll.

I can see similar questions like this one: [Interactive grid in Oracle APEX - Only 40 rows are selected, if I do 'Select All'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54823218/interactive-grid-in-oracle-apex-only-40-rows-are-selected-if-i-do-select-all)
but it is not really what I'm after.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to select all the rows in IG
Because the default functionality of IG is that, it will always select the first loaded set of records.